# Missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, class, typeerror, positional-argument

```
class classname:
    def createname(self, name):
        self.name = name;
    def displayname(self):
        return self.name;
    def saying(self):
        print("Hello %s" % self.name);

first = classname;
second = classname;

first.createname("Bobby");
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    first.createname("Bobby")
TypeError: createname() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

---

The error tells me that I need 1 more argument in the name, so I must be going wrong there, but I already tried something like this:

```
first.createname("bobby", "timmy");
```

I also rule out the fact that it would be the `def createname(self, name)`, because `self` is or should be alone and not included? So I do not really understand what is going on.

Comment: Sorry to say but in python the semicolon (“;”) is never used on the end of a line... (There are exception, but those are bad practice too)

Answer (score 27):

You have not actually *created an object* yet.

For instance, you would want to write:

```
first = classname()
```

instead of just

```
first = classname
```

At the moment, how you wrote it, `first` is pointing to a **class**.  E.g., if you ask what `first` is, you'd get:

```
<class '__main__.classname'>
```

However, after instantiating it (by simply adding the `()` at the end), you'd see that `first` is now:

```
<__main__.classname object at 0x101cfa3c8>
```

The important distinction here is that *your* call set `first` as a ***class***, whereas mine set it as an ***object***.

Think about it like this: A class is to an object as humankind is to you, or as canine is to Lassie.

You set it as "canine", whereas you wanted to set it as "Lassie".

---

**Note**:  you also usually want to initialize your objects.  For that, you place an `__init__` method in your class.